Should Bitcoin centric questions related to Quantative Finance be asked here?
I'm looking for a home for a downvoted & closed question that requires not only a deep understanding of the Bitcoin network, but also of Quant. Finance.
I believe this is something that could eventually become a forum of it's own due to the unique attributes of the Bitcoin network + quant finance, but for now the emerging Bitcoin standard needs as many eyes on it as possible.
So the question is... should this SE site accept advanced finance questions? ... at least until the user community is large enough to sustain a dedicated Bitcoin-quant site of its own.
Finally, how should these questions be tagged, so users can easily search for (or ignore) such questions?

This is a tough question: How to best handle interdisciplinary questions? 
There's no ideal answer that fits all cases. The best guidance I can give you is to remember that the purpose behind a "Bitcoin Stack Exchange" is to build a compilation of knowledge about the subject of "Bitcoin" — It cannot reasonably become a site about any possible questions of interest to Bitcoin *users*.
See the difference?
The best acid test I have right now is: "Is this question primarily about Bitcoin? Or is it really about another discipline that just happens to involve some Bitcoin issues?"
So on the face of it, the closure looks justified. The main focus of the question is in financial issues. It's just a fortunate (or unfortunate) coincidence that it takes a bit of Bitcoin understanding to answer the question. It's not really a question for a Bitcoin expert.
It's not an idea answer because it doesn't leave a clear home for this question. But know that the issue of interdisciplinary collaboration is a problem across all academia.  
